# How do I pass arguments to an XML::SAX parser?

Tags: xml, perl, sax

I've got an XML::SAX::Base-based parser that looks something like this:

```
package MyParser;
use base qw(XML::SAX::Base);
our @ISA = ('XML::SAX::Base');

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %params = @_;

    my $self = {
        thing   => $params{thing},
    };
    bless $self, $class;

    return $self;
}

sub start_element {
    my ($self, $data) = @_;
    # Do something useful using $data & $self->{thing}
}
1;
```

And I'm using it with XML::SAX::ParserFactory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use MyParser;

my $parser = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser(
                Handler => MyParser->new
            );
$parser->parse_string('<document/>');
```

Is there a way that I can pass arguments to MyParser's new() subroutine?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the passed arguments?

Comment: The XML document I'm parsing is actually from Ganglia's gmetad and I'm pushing it over a socket to another monitoring system (Graphite), so I want to be able to pass in the socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `new` method is already set up to receive arguments using `%params`, so just pass your arguments as a hash:

```
my $parser = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser(
            Handler => MyParser->new(param1=>$value1, param2=>$value2, ...)
        );
```

Then in your `new` method you can access the arguments as you would any other hash:

```
$param1 = $params{param1};
$param2 = $params{param2};
...
```

Comment: Hah, I swear I tried that and thought it didn't work...easy peasy.